# java.io.FileNotFoundException: Pago Atuq.pdf (Permission denied). java.io.FileOutputStream.open0

Tags: java, spring-boot, centos7, tomcat9

I am having a problem with my Tomcat. Installed on a CentOS, I have a functionality, which until a few days ago worked and suddenly it began to throw this error:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file.pdf (Permission denied)

Note: When I run it on my machine it works perfect, when uploading it to the server, this error appears

Code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream reporte = getImprimeVenta(venta);
byte[] bytes = reporte.toByteArray();
File archivo = new File("Venta.pdf");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(archivo);
fos.write(bytes);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

Comment: check user owner and permissions (chmod, chown), this is a Linux issue and not Java coding.

Comment: Perfect, I understand that this is my problem and I have changed permissions, but I still have the problem. Do you know in which folder it keeps these temporary files? / temp I already gave it and it didn't work

Comment: Probably it is written in the tomcat root path; the easiest solution would be to give an absolute path to File

Comment: Thank you very much, I am already changing permissions and testing, still without luck